# SQL Server Replace

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE test (a VARCHAR(2000))

INSERT INTO test 
VALUES ('This is a AB_CD_test.dbo.ABC'), 
       ('This is a AB_CD.dbo.ABC')
```

Table before running `Update` query:

```
This is a AB_CD_test.dbo.ABC
This is a AB_CD.dbo.ABC
This is a [AB_CD].[dbo].[XYZ]
```

I am trying to replace the keyword `AB_CD` with `AB_CD_test` using this query:

```
UPDATE [US\AF83767].[test]
SET a = REPLACE(a, 'AB_CD', 'AB_CD_test')
WHERE a LIKE '%AB!_CD%' ESCAPE '!';
```

But as expected, data changes to:

```
This is a AB_CD_test_test.dbo.ABC
This is a AB_CD_test.dbo.ABC
This is a [AB_CD_test].[dbo].[XYZ]
```

The second is fine but the first should remain 'This is a AB_CD_test.dbo.ABC'.

Could anyone help with a query which does not change the first row and just looks for occurrences of 'AB_CD'.

Relatively new to SQL and would appreciate your help.

Comment: add in... `and a NOT LIKE '%AB!_CD_test%' ESCAPE '!';` or you could use `and charindex('test',a) = 0` in the where clause. Good job on your first post--your sample data, sample code, and expected output is why you are getting so many upvotes. Keep it up!

Comment: The problem is in `!` character - your `REPLACE` and 'LIKE' do not match.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear what you want to prevent.  Do you only want to prevent the replacement when "Test" is present, or any string between "AB_CD" and ".dbo"

I'm guessing the latter, so I would suggest this:

```
UPDATE [US\AF83767].[test]
SET a = REPLACE(a, 'AB_CD', 'AB_CD_test')
WHERE a LIKE '%AB!_CD.%' ESCAPE '!';
```

Comment: I just want to replace the occurence of 'AB_CD' with 'AB_CD_test'. Can't use your solution as AB_CD is a database and sometimes it's been qualified. For eg. FROM [AB_CD].[dbo].[TestTable]. I have added another row of sample data in my question to make the requirements clear. Apologies, if it were vague.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to replace instances of AB_CD ONLY WHEN it is  followed by a period or a closing bracket or  nothing at all.

```
where col like '%AB!_CD[.!]]%' ESCAPE '!' or col like '%AB!_CD' ESCAPE '!';
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you want:

```
UPDATE #test
SET a = REPLACE(REPLACE(a, 'AB_CD_test', 'AB_CD'), 'AB_CD', 'AB_CD_test')
WHERE a LIKE '%AB!_CD%' ESCAPE '!';
```

It replaces all occurrences of AB_CD_test to AB_CD... and then changes all AB_CD to AB_CD_test.